# cl command line option in VS2012 replication

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have the following command which works

```
cl -nologo -W3 -O2 -MD -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -I C:\Tcl\include\ -c example.cpp
```

However I would like to build my project using VS2012 and I wanted to know where would

```
-DUSE_TCL_STUBS
```

go ? How would I inert that in Visual Studio 2012?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to *Project Property Pages->C/C++->Preprocessor*, add `USE_TCL_STUBS` to *Preprocessor Definitions*